# Collapsing/expanding Toolbar only on double click WITH a framelayout that is not covered by the toolbar

Tags: android

For my existing app I would like the following change:

- By default the Toolbar/Appbar is visible. The contents of the FrameLayout starts below the toolbar. So, nothing of the Framelayout is covered by the Toolbar.
- On a user action, e.g. by a double click, the Toolbar/Appbar should collapse. The Framelayout should stretch to the top of the page.
- No collapsing of the Toolbar/Appbar is needed upon scrolling the content of the Framelayout.

How can I get this behaviour? Till so far I face the following issues: [1](https://github.com/johan974/android-collapsable-toolbar-on-tap.git) the Toolbar/Appbar collapses when I scroll the FrameLayout and [2] part of the Framelayout is covered by the Toolbar/Appbar.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:itemIconTint="#333"
                app:itemTextColor="#333"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
         <!-- see this line above. The string is defined below -->    

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items"
        app:itemIconTint="#fcc"
        app:itemTextColor="#000" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The layout string is:

```
<string name="appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" translatable="false">android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior</string>
```

**SOLUTION:**

Below you find the great solution created by **Rabee**. The credits and bounty credits are his!

Based on that solution, I created a simple Git project showing all gestures easily. Double clicking on the specified content will expand or collapse the toolbar. Clicking on the toolbar will collapse the toolbar.

Enjoy the [Git demo project](https://github.com/johan974/android-collapsable-toolbar-on-tap.git) that uses AndroidX and JDK8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following (with activity_main.xml in the code below being the layout you posted):

1) MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private AppBarLayout appbar;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private FrameLayout content_frame;
private TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);

    appbar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    content_frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View framelayout_content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.framelayout_content, null, false);
    content_frame.addView(framelayout_content);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            appbar.setExpanded(true);
        }
    });

    toolbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            MainActivity.this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return false;

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    appbar.setExpanded(false);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    return false;
}
}
```

2) framelayout_content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    </View>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

3) Result:

[image: result]